# Cannot use zoom in windows without resizable

Tags: python, tkinter

Why can't I use zoomed state in non resizable window?

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False, False)
root.state('zoomed')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: See [ask]. Provide more details.

Comment: You haven't asked a question in your question.

Comment: To put it simply, don't do that.  Setting `resizable` to false prevents the user from resizing.  It doesn't prevent the programmer from doing it.